# how to run pipenv in cronjob in ubuntu?

Tags: python, shell, cron, pipenv

I have installed pipenv by pip3.
And it works pipenv -h in script.
But after in crontab, it's not work.

pip3 show pipenv
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

my cronjob
`21 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test; /bin/sh test.sh > /home/ubuntu/test.out 2>&1`

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"

python -V
python3 -V
pipenv -h
```

output
hi
Python 2.7.12
Python 3.6.3
test.sh: : test.sh: pipenv: not found

how to run pipenv in cronjob in ubuntu?
thanks.

Answer:
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/pipen

Comment: The problem is that cron has a limited environment. Please have a look at [this canonical answer :: why is my crontab not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it). Especially the section _cron runs your command in a restricted environment_. If you do not know where your binary is located you can type the following in the console `which pipenv`

Answer (score 18):

Try giving the whole path.

Find which pipenv and then run with the absolute path of the same.
instead of pipenv -h

In my case it was located in `/usr/local/bin/pipenv`

Comment: Thank u, But I can not find the path.   
It was not located in `/usr/local/bin/pipenv` in ubuntu.   
I used pip3 install pipenv.   
Do u know how to find the actual path in ubuntu16.04?

Comment: Thank u I found in /home/ubuntu/.local/bin

Comment: For future reference: Running `which pipenv` should say where pipenv is located :)

Answer (score 0):

Exmaple:

```
20 * * * * bash -lc mypythonscript
```

This will bring in your paths defined in your bashrc/profile etc