# How schedule crontab job when using pyenv and pipenv

Tags: python, bash, cron, pipenv, pyenv

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and I am having issues setting up the **crontab** correctly using `pyenv` + `pipenv` together. Simply adding `pipenv run python script.py` to the cronjob does not work; I think it may be due to:

1. the environment required by `pyenv`
2. the non-interactive shell of cronjob

## UPDATED BIG QUESTION

How do I use `/home/jennings/.pyenv/shims/pipenv` correctly in crontab??

I've checked `$?` for `pipenv -v` in `run.sh` scheduled in crontab, and it fails.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#advanced-configuration

## 00. (for reference) Bash startup

`pyenv` requires these entries in these startup files for interactive/login shells I don't understand how to translate this to a non-interactive cronjob call. How do I set up my BASH_ENV to emmulate these environents below?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9954208/9335288

```
# ~/.profile
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
fi
```

```
# ~/.bashrc:
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
```

## I. Crontab

I am trying to effectively write a .profile for the cronjob... but if you a better solution, please let me know.

**# CRONTAB**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV="home/jennings/.custom_bash_env
# BASH_ENV="home/jennings/.profile"
# BASH_ENV="home/jennings/.bashrc"
* * * * * cd $PROJECT_DIR; ./run.sh
```

**# BASH_ENV**:

> Should I point to .profile or .bashrc instead?*

```
# PYENV
#eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
#if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
#  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
#fi

# ENV VARIABLES
PYENV_ROOT="/home/jennings/.pyenv"
PYTHONPATH=$SOMEPLACE
PATH=all:of:them:paths
```

## II. Project Folder

**# run.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# PYENV
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
fi
# actual pipenv command I'm trying to run
pipenv run python main.py
```

**# main.py**:

```
import this
# Does some python and logging
```

## What I've tried and know

- Pointing directly at the .profile and .bashrc doesn't work
- `run.sh` will run okay; it's the`pipenv` step that fails
- Scheduling other non-pipenv commands work fine

### `pyenv init` block

- Placed in the `BASH_ENV` file, the cronjob doesn't run at all
- Placed in the `run.sh`, the cronjob now runs, but the `pipenv run` still fails

### pipenv related

- I've tried pipenv shell; which python to use that one in the crontab enjoy -- no cigar

Comment: `cron` does not run any of your interactive startup files. If you want to load settings from those, you need to explicitly `source` them.

Comment: Using backslashes where you mean slash is rather distracting. Windows (bless its soul) accepts forward slash as a replacement for the OS native backslash directory separator, but backslash on Unix is always an escape character.

Comment: @tripleee I have tried sourcing them, but it didn't work. How would you recommend doing that (in which file, in which order?). The `BASH_ENV=.custom_env`? And then .custom_env would contain something like `source .profile; source.bashrc`?

Comment: @tripleee sorry about the slashes, my brain is fried from trying to figure this out. Fixed them tho

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `pyenv` internals to post an answer. What I usually do is combine `pyenv` with `venv` and then just activate the `venv` when I need it; but I know this is not common practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron has a limited environment. You have to declare the full path to the pipenv executable. Instead of using `pipenv run python script.py` you should use `/usr/local/bin/pipenv run python script.py`.

In your case the full path can be different `which pipenv` will give you the proper path.

This is explained in this post [how to run pipenv in cronjob in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342202/how-to-run-pipenv-in-cronjob-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I have forgottent to mention that you also have to add a `cd /path/to/the/pipenv/project;` before your script, so that pipenv knows which environment he has to activate.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I updated, but I also addressed the issue by removing `pyenv` from the equation. I just used the OS-level `python` and `pipenv` of the server instead (which means I'm locked on a particular python version, but as long as it works). Your comments are also true and definitely helpful